# How to access data sent in post request?

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have this code,

```
var items = '{"items":[{"Desc":"item1"}]}';
items = JSON.parse(items);
var data = items;
$.post( "send.php", function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

How to get the items?

Here is my php code,

```
<?php
 echo $_POST['items'];
?>
```

is $_POST['items']; correct?

Comment: Did you try and execute the code?

Comment: print_r( $_POST['items']); to check what is in the post

Comment: You are not passing data to php code . Try this  ``$.post( "send.php", {items: data}, function( data )``

Comment: In fact at your first line you have all what you need to send inside the post.. no stringify shits must be made.. You need just to put it at its proper place at $.post after the URL and before the Function.. "send.php", items, function().. The data inside your function is the callback which you will receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try this

```
 <?php 
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($_POST["items"]), true);
    echo $data['items'][0]['Desc'];
 ?>
```

Comment: This will work but its not a real fix of the issue, its a way to make the wrong code working..

Answer (score 0):

Your:

```
$.post( "send.php", function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

Should be:

```
$.post( "send.php", data, function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

the second parameter is where your post data should be to pass in `send.php`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JSON.stringify` your data before posting it. Also your `$.post` function looks to be incorrect.

```
var items = {items: [{Desc:'item1'}]};//'{"items":[{"Desc":"item1"}]}';
items = JSON.stringify(items);
var data = items;
$.post( "send.php", data)
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/